# Deploying a React-Redux Webpack 2 app to GitHub pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have looked at all the documentation of deploy a react app to GitHub pages and none of it has worked or is applicable. This is driving me up the wall, when Webpack is involved, but I am trying to master Webpack here.

So, I did not originally have a `dist` folder for my project.

Then I learned you have to put your files in a `dist` folder and push to `gh-pages`. Well, in my GitHub repo, I do not have that option the way the GitHub docs say I do. My only options are `master` and `/docs`.

This is a React 15 app with Redux and Webpack 2.

I am getting a blank browser here:
https://ldco2016.github.io/JSFaddle/

It failed to load resource of bundle.js and style.css and I do not know why. I have yet to have any luck deploying to GitHub pages.

I tweaked my webpack to include a dist folder, but nothing is being built into it, the folder is empty.

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

I believe this is the root of my problem, but webpack is still a bit of a mystery to me because of the myriad of configurations you can do.

This continues to be a good working app in my local environment, but there is something I am not understanding in the deployment process.

To be clear, I did not previously have a `dist` directory when developing locally and after I created a `dist` directory, none of my static assets were being dumped there.

Comment: I would recommend to upgrade both webpack and React

Comment: @SuperDJ, what would this do? It seems all docs suggest a folder of `dist` which I tried creating manually, but the build would not save anything there, so I am not sure how upgrading the version would help.

Comment: at this point it wouldn't do much except that React have changed quite a bit in the recent updates. Also webpack should be easier to configure.

Comment: @SuperDJ, I honestly have never had Webpack help me on any project. I think I will just recreate this project using `create-react-app`. No matter what I do, Webpack always successfully foils my projects when I involve it.

Comment: You can also take a loot at https://parceljs.org/

Answer (score 0):

For hosting on GitHub pages you will have to server index.html of built react-app.
So your gh-pages/master should have index.html at the root and not within some folder named as dist.

Your bundle.js is not getting generated because webpack config is incorrect. You are not specifying resource type for babel-loader to process.
Please use the below config which I have corrected and tested on my local.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Comment: I actually have nothing in my `dist/` folder. In fact I just deleted it. And I do have my index.html in the root of my project. If you are correct, I should be able to then do `git push origin master` and the app should be working in the browser, but it does not, I continue to get a 404 for bundle.js and style.css.

Comment: can you add link of git repo that you are trying to serve. also check that outputPath option that i have mentioned in answer.

Comment: My dist folder was always empty, so yes there is a problem with my webpack config, that is what I am asking about.

Comment: @Daniel can you give git repo link so that i can take a look.

Comment: @Daniel check the answer have updated it and tested also.